# Calculating the Dihedral Angle of a Lateral Face and Base

Tags: geometry

The question is as follows:

> Let $P = (4,4,7), A = (0,0,0), B = (8,0,0), C = (8,8,0),$ and $D = (0,8,0)$. These points are the vertices of a *regular square pyramid*. Sketch it. To the nearest tenth of a degree, find the size of the dihedral angle formed by *lateral face* $PCD$ and *base* $ABCD$.

I have no clue as to how I should start. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Two Possible Methods:

1.

> Use the triangle formed by $P$, the center of the base, which is $(4, 4, 0)$, and the midpoint between $C$ and $D$, which is $(4, 8, 0)$. This is a right triangle with a base of 4 and a height of 7. The opposite of the angle you want is $7$ and the adjacent is $4$, meaning the answer to your problem is $\arctan\left(\frac 7 4\right) = 60.3^\circ$

2.

> You can find the normals of these faces easily using cross products:
>   $$(C-P)\times(D-P) = N_{PCD} = \langle0, 56, 32\rangle$$
>   $$(B-A)\times(C-A) = N_{ABC} = N_{ABCD} = \langle 0, 0, 64\rangle$$
>   Then, use the identity
>   $$a\cdot b = |a||b|\cos(\theta)$$
>   with $N_{PCD}$ and $N_{ABCD}$ to get:
>   $$N_{PCD}\cdot N_{ABCD} = 0+0+2048 = \sqrt{4160}\cdot 64\cdot \cos(\theta)$$
>   $$\rightarrow\theta=\arccos\bigg(\frac{2048}{64\sqrt{4160}}\bigg)\approx 1.05165021$$
>   or about $60.2551187^{\circ}$.